# Prices and numbers of transactions

Tags: exchange-rate, market, volume

At https://coinbase.com/charts we see that $/BTC ratio has been pretty steady for the past week, while the number of transactions per day has plummeted from more than 120,000 to fewer than 27,000.

I'd have guessed that the price would be more sensitive to the number of transactions.  Is there some explanation of why it's not?

Comment: Number of transactions are irrelevant, I'd think exchange volume and coin days destroyed would be a good indicator of increased activity.